# What is a resource for a side-by-side correspondence between coding and formulas in the mixed effects `lmer` package?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, references, random-effects-model

In the `lmer` package in R, it contains terminology for coding in random effects and mixed effects for a linear model. I am wondering if there exists a manual or resource online where they compare both the code and the actual corresponding statistical model write-up side-by-side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best free, online resource I have seen that places the code directly next to the statistical model: http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer